# How to create RSS reader for HTML5-based IPhone application using JqueryMobile?

Tags: iphone, html, rss, jquery-mobile

How to create `RSS` reader for `HTML5-based IPhone` application ? do I need `PHP` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a server at all, except the one you want to fetch the RSS feed from...

PHP sample: Check [this out](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/) for a complete example!

Client-only sample: [link](http://www.appin8.com/blog-post/mobile-rss-reader-google-feeds-api-jquerymobile-localstorage/)

Hope this helps

Comment: they are just using PHP to render a hard-coded JqueryMobile HTML page and content. Here's [another example](http://www.appin8.com/blog-post/mobile-rss-reader-google-feeds-api-jquerymobile-localstorage/) with NO SERVER SIDE CODE AT ALL (retrieves online from Google API RSS)