# how to create a local RSS reader for iphone using HTML5

Tags: iphone, ios, html, rss, jquery-mobile

I am creating HTML5-based iPhone application. How to create a local RSS reader using JQurtyMobile , I don't want to host the HTML files on a server, rather, the HTML files are hosted locally in the iphone project folder

Answer (score 0):

you should check this out with both server-side and only client-side implementation:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325394/how-to-create-rss-reader-for-html5-based-iphone-application-using-jquerymobile/8325593#8325593)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own RSS reader still in html + javascript and deploy it as an app, you can use PhoneGap.
PhoneGap allows you to store the html + javascript on the device, and then run it as an app.
It's exactly what you're asking for.

If you think phonegap is too big or confusing, you just need to follow one of the several UIWebview tutorials out on the web to write your own wrapper. It takes only a couple of minutes if you are familiar with objective c and Xcode. If that is not the case, it will take you some days, and phone gap adds lots of nice extra features.

for example:
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/26/uiwebview-tutorial-link-to-an-ibaction/